# Mathematical logic problem

Tags: logic, problem-solving

Could somebody please help me solve the following logic-problem (it's translated, so I hope it makes sense):

Facts:

1. If Michael coughs and his face is white, he is either sick or
   has gone around the corner to smoke
2. If Michael hasn't smoked and still has a cough or
   is white in the face, then he is sick.
3. When Michael is sick, he coughs, but his face is not white.

When Michael came to class after the break, his face was completely white. What is the conclusion - is he sick or did he have a smoke break?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.

Comment: Hint: $~G = ~$ cough, $~W = ~$ white, $~S = ~$ sick, $~K = ~$ smoke.  Convert the premises into compound logic statements, involving $~G,W,S,~$ and $~K.~$  Then, assume that both $W$ is true and $K$ is false, and see where it leads.

Comment: all logic aside... he smoked xD

Comment: @user2661923 Oh im sorry if it came out that way. I have been trying to get a grasp on the fundamentals of discrete mathematics on my own but couldn't figure out that problem from a textbook I'm using. Either way what I know is that I need to make a table, just couldn't figure out how to do it with four different aspects

Comment: Or [Guidelines for attracting Answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813), easier to read. @user2661923

Comment: @ryang there is a link to that article in the comment following the article that I linked to.  I agree that the 2nd article is easier to read.  Part of the reason is that I have included special sections on Tools and Images.  By linking to my article instead, I am compromising, by linking to more detailed information that is somewhat more difficult to digest.  What is the **sweet spot**?  I really don't know.  I like Calvin Khor's article, but continue to link to mine, because I don't regard my article as *that* difficult to read.

Comment: @user2661923 Lol sorry I hadn't noticed that you're the article's author, in which case of course I know that you're aware of its offshoot. I prefer linking to the table to *increase the chance of a new user actually reading it*, because I've been involved in crafting it to be as easy as possible to digest and integrate, and because it links (as a nota bene) to your article (its parent) in case the new user doesn't mind an elaboration. (I've been suggesting the table recently as most of us aren't aware that it has a streamlined newer version.) Thanks again for that excellent article.

Comment: @ryang You bring up a very interesting point.  I am in favor of linking to whichever article has the greater probability of influencing the original poster to edit their posting to improve its quality.  This is not necessarily the same as increasing the probability of the original poster reading the underlying article, but **it's close**.  What has your *anecdotal experience* been?  Have a significant number of users been improving their posts after having read Calvin Khor's article, instead of mine?  ...see next comment

Comment: Frankly, I suspect that the only positive effect of my article is that new users will often only post a low-quality article *once*.  The exception is when someone posts an answer anyway, thus encouraging the new user to not make additional effort.  However, I see no defense (on my part) to that.  I especially want the users to see the *excrutiating detail* phrase, as well as the **Edit-Images** and **Edit-Tools** portions of my article.

Comment: To the original poster.  Take another look at my **second** comment.  Actually, a truth table **is not necessary**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the following hold:
$(1)\text{ }$ $(A\wedge B)\implies (C\vee D)$,
$(2) \text{ }$ $(\neg D\wedge (A\vee B))\implies C$,
$(3)\text{ }$ $C\implies (A\wedge \neg B)$

Then the question asks which of the following also holds?:
$$B\implies C\text{ }\text{ }\text{ or }\text{ }\text{ }B\implies D$$
Make a truth table for all statements involved and find rows where all of (1-3) are true, if a conclusion is true in the same rows as these are true then logical implication has been found.